# Eloquent wherehas slow consult

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I try a consult with eloquent, but is very slow.
My code

```
$users = $this->user
                     ->whereHas('friends', function($q) use($id)
                     {
                        $q->where('friend_id', '=', $id)
                          ->where('state', '=', 'accepted');
                     })
                    ->take(16)
                    ->orderBy('name','asc')
                    ->get();
```

SQL generate

```
select  *
    from  `users`
    where  `users`.`deleted_at` is null
      and  
      ( SELECT  count(*)
            from  `friends` as `self_04b17053094a40fb70514325b892fc19`
            where  `users`.`deleted_at` is null
              and  `self_04b17053094a40fb70514325b892fc19`.`user_id` = `users`.`id`
              and  `friend_id` = '1'
              and  `state` = 'accepted'
              and  `users`.`deleted_at` is null
      ) >= 1
    order by  `name` asc
    limit  16
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: More of an sql problem, i believe. Have you tried creating indexes on your composite keys?

Comment: Recently this was optimized in Laravel 5.2, so if you upgrade you should get much better performance particularly in PostgreSQL and SQLServer.